# How to make login api Laravel default session

Tags: laravel

Actually, I have made login and registration API, now I want to make the Laravel login session to the live server. But I am unable to manage the Laravel login API default session. How can I solve this problem?

**Here is my Laravel login API function: Laravel version-8**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'user_id' => ['required'],
            'user_token' => ['required'],
            'project_token' => ['required'],
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'errors' => $validator->errors()->toArray()
            ]);
        }

        $project_user_token = DB::table('users')
                ->where('user_id', $request->user_id)
                ->where('user_token',$request->user_token)
                ->where('project_token',$request->project_token)
                ->get()
                ->toArray();

        if($project_user_token){
            return response()->json([
                'success' => 'true',
            ]);
        }else{
            return response()->json([
                'success' => 'false',
                'reason' => 'Your user id, user token or project token invalid!',
            ], 401);
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: @Ron van der Heijden
No, I don't want a browser session, I want a session server.

Comment: To maintain session you need to start utilizing session first, and for that I'd advise you to go through this and implement this as per your need https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session